# Enviando XML para JAVA - Angular 2

Tags: java, http, post, angular

Galera, estou tentando enviar um XML da minha view em Angular 2 para um backend em Java. No java possuo um servlet que busca o xml pelo parametro:

`request.getParameter("xml")`

E no meu servico do angular estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

`let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();`

`urlSearchParams.append('xml', params);`

`let body = urlSearchParams.toString();`

`return this._http.post(url, body).map(this.extractJson);`

Onde o `params` é o xml, que vem como parâmetro da função. A URL está correta, debugando o Java recebo o request mas o parâmetro vem nulo. Alguma coisa errada que estou fazendo?